# What are better lenses for portrait photography (1.8D or 1.8G) for Nikon D750?

Tags: lens, portrait, wedding, nikon-d750

I am planning to start home-based wedding photography business and the compiling a list of gear to purchase.I have planned to purchase D750 as my primary body but I can't seem to decide on which lens to go for portrait photography i.e. 1.8D or 1.8G

Which one is an all in one option taken that I am a beginner and really tight on budget as well.

Comment: *I am planning to start home-based wedding photography business* and *I am a beginner* aren't two things usually seen in the same question. Might I suggest that you begin your career with simple portraits before committing to documenting one of the most important milestones in someone's life?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.8D lenses are old and noisy because of the motor. They are not compatible with all nikon cameras. They are faster by fraction compared with 1.8G but it doesn't affect the picture quality. In terms of picture quality both lenses produce same result. 1.8G are silent and compatible with almost all nikon cameras.

If you are planning to buy a portrait lens and have good budget then go with nikon 85mm 1.8G. Else you can go with 50mm 1.8G and upgrade to 85mm later.

Comment: I agree with the first paragraph (not enough for an answer) *but* to save $ and weight I'd pick the D 87% of the time.